# How to add R^2 in R via latex for regression output?

Tags: r, latex, linear-regression

I want to add R^2 also below this latex formulation. just like in textbook forms. How can I do this : [image]

```
$$\hat{Y}_{t} =  \underset{(0.1216)}{2.6911} \underset{(0.1140 )}{-0.4795}X_{t} \tag{7.8.8}$$
```

Comment: `$$r^2 = 0.6629$$`?

Comment: That's cool but do u know how can I write this below the equation?